# Qt: QHeaderView place sort-indicator on the right of the header text

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qheaderview

If I set: `QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-position: center left}`, the down-arrow is on the left of the column, and if I set `center right`, it is placed on the right of the column, but I want to place the arrow next to the title (on the right side).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I sorted was by creating a QProxyStyle for the header, and override drawControl.
I also assigned an empty icon to hide the default one.

`treeviewwidget.cpp` at initialize():

```
treeviewHeaderProxy* m_oHeaderStyle = new treeviewHeaderProxy();
treeview->header()->setStyle(m_oHeaderStyle);
treeview->header()->setDefaultAlignment(Qt::AlignCenter);
treeview->header()->setStyleSheet("QHeaderView::down-arrow { image: url(:/shared/empty); }"
                                "QHeaderView::up-arrow { image: url(:/shared/empty); } ");
```

---

`treeviewHeaderProxy.h`:

```
class treeviewHeaderProxy : public QProxyStyle
{
public:
    explicit treeviewHeaderProxy();
    void drawControl(ControlElement oCtrElement, const QStyleOption * poStylrOptionption, QPainter * poPainter, const QWidget * poWidget = 0) const;

};
```

---

`treeviewHeaderProxy.cpp`:

```
void treeviewHeaderProxy::drawControl(ControlElement oCtrElement, const QStyleOption *poStyleOptionption, QPainter *poPainter, const QWidget *poWidget) const
{
    // Header label?
    if (oCtrElement == CE_HeaderLabel) {
        QStyleOptionHeader *poStyleOptionHeader = (QStyleOptionHeader *) poStyleOptionption;
        QStyleOptionHeader::SortIndicator sortOption = poStyleOptionHeader->sortIndicator;
        QRect oRect = poStyleOptionHeader->rect;

        // Text
        int iTextWidth = poStyleOptionHeader->fontMetrics.width(poStyleOptionHeader->text);
        int iTextHeight = poStyleOptionHeader->fontMetrics.height();
        QRect oTextRect = QRect(oRect.left() + oRect.width(), catRect.top() + (oRect.height() - iTextHeight)/2,
                                iTextWidth*1.2, iTextHeight);
        poPainter->setPen(SUPER_DARK_GREY);
        poPainter->drawText(oTextRect, poStyleOptionHeader->text); // Draw text

        // Sort Indicator
        QPixmap oSortPixmap;
        switch(sortOption){
        case QStyleOptionHeader::SortDown:
            oSortPixmap = QIcon(":/shared/drop_up_grey").pixmap(10,10);
            break;
        case QStyleOptionHeader::SortUp:
            oSortPixmap = QIcon(":/shared/drop_down_grey").pixmap(10,10);
            break;
        }

        if(!oSortPixmap.isNull()){
            QRect oSortRect = QRect(oTextRect.left() + oTextRect.width(), oRect.top() + (oRect.height() - oSortPixmap.height())/2,
                                    oSortPixmap.width(), oSortPixmap.height());
            poPainter->drawPixmap(oSortRect, oSortPixmap); // Draw sortIcon
        }
        return;
    }
    QProxyStyle::drawControl(oCtrElement, poStyleOptionption, poPainter, poWidget);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to set `subcontrol-origin: margin | border | padding | content`;

Look into below documentation link to understand box model ( which explains the margin rectangle, the border rectangle, the padding rectangle, and the content rectangle).

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#the-box-model

So try adding `subcontrol-origin:padding` to your code, which may add next to your content.

Try something like below:

```
QHeaderView::down-arrow { subcontrol-origin:padding; subcontrol-position: center right;}
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the arrow is placed on the right side. The center of the arrow is in the right corner, so I can only see half of the arrow... I tried using subcontrol-origin and changing the possibles values, to see if there was any difference, but it doesn't seem to make any effect.